# Breaking apart factorials

Tags: discrete-mathematics, factorial

Say you have a factorial like this in an equality:

$\frac{(x-1)!}{((x-1)!-(y-1)!)!}$

Is there any way to split it apart? How can it be manipulated? The second factorial seems to complicate things.

Comment: Do we know if $x>y$?

Comment: @turkeyhundt Yes! 1<=y<=x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{(x-1)!}{((x-1)!-(y-1)!)!}=\frac{(x-1)!}{\left(-\frac{xy!-yx!}{xy}\right)!}=\frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma\left(\Gamma(x)-\Gamma(y)-1\right)}=\frac{\Gamma(x)}{\left(\Gamma(x)-\Gamma(y)\right)!}$$

Comment: Though it's not clear what the OP wants as a splitting apart or a manipulation, I can't imagine any sense in which this calculation would be useful.  If it is useful, then it should probably be shortened by going directly from the first term to the last, by the identity $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$, without the intermediate detour.

Comment: I was trying to get an idea of how this factorization might work, because I have a large equation to prove with a few different variations of double factorial. I'm thinking now that won't be the right path, but I appreciate the insight!